# Apollo caching with React redirect doesn't get new items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo Client.

There's a route `/restaurants/${restaurant_name}/places` where it lists all the places for concrete restaurant_name.

Let's say I am on the `/restaurans/france_res/places` route. On that route, I can add new `place` for it. I add it and when it's done, I redirect users with `history.push` to the following route - `/restaurans/france_res/places/place_name`.

Now, if user goes to `/restaurans/france_res/places` route again (with no refresh, just react router's navigation), Apollo doesn't query the server any more and the places that route shows doesn't include the new one. This is because of the cache policy and it seems like the route `/restaurans/france_res/places` is already cached...

What could be the workaround for the following situation ?

1. using `no-cache` policy seems too harsh... Then what's the point of Apollo's caching policies in the first place ?
2. I don't use Redux, but I don't know how that could help me. There's a way with Redux, but it's not good.
3. Maybe, when new `place` gets added, I make user redirect to the route without `history.push` which will cause the hard refresh, causing queries to get executed again.

How do you handle situation like this ?

Comment: `network-only` policy? update query cache after mutation (read docs)?

Comment: `network-only` executes a new query, but its results are merged with the old ones... Pretty strange.. @xadm

Comment: This happens because for the list ,I have a `mergeFunction` and merge old one with the new one... I don't know when to replace and when to merge now :(